# Can't make android buttons touch each other

Tags: android, xml, button

I have 5 buttons lined up in a row inside a linear layout and I cannot get them to touch each other. For some reason there is a padding between the buttons.  [image]

The above image shows what my current android application is displaying when it runs. Can someone please help with what I have to do to make them touch while also filling the screens width? I have included the XML code below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/options_selected">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/stats_unselected">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stats"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/camera_unselected">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/shop_unselected">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/profile_unselected">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of layout_weight=1 without height or width 0. don't misuse layout_weight and that is the main problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this layout: use `weightSum` property on parent layout

and for child element use: `android:layout_width="0dp"` with `android:layout_weight="1"`.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="0dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="0dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stats"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="0dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shop"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="0dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="0dp"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I cleaned a bunch of wrong attributes & set the height in one place alos when using weights, it is better to give width 0dp):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:weightSum="5">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/options_selected">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/stats_unselected">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stats"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/camera_unselected">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shop"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/shop_unselected">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/profile_unselected">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add attribute `android:orientation="horizontal"` and `android:weightSum="5"` to `LinearLayout02`.
2. Use `Button` width as `android:layout_width="0dp"` instead of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
3. Remove redundant attributes `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`, `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` from all buttons.

**Here is the working XML:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/options_selected">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/stats_unselected">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stats"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/camera_unselected">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shop"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/shop_unselected">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/profile_unselected">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

**[image: OUTPUT]**

Hope this will help~